# Manually send to iperf via UDP socket? (C++)

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp, iperf

I have a program that needs to measure total loss after routing through a machine.

Essentially, I generate UDP traffic with `iperf` on machine A that is destined for machine C. However, I first route this traffic through machine B**, then send it to machine C via a raw socket to port 5001 (the default port that `iperf` listens to) with `sendto()`. While running a `tcpdump` shows that the packets are being received on machine C, the `iperf` server doesn't see these connections or the packet.

I've hunted around the `iperf` source code a bit to see how it works, and I see that packets are accepted with the function

```
rc = recvfrom( mSettings->mSock, mBuf, mSettings->mBufLen, 0, 
                       (struct sockaddr*) &server->peer, &server->size_peer );.
```

Basically, because its simply a `recvfrom`, I don't see why there's a problem if I'm very sure I'm not modifying the packets at any time, and am sending them with the function `sendto(s, buf, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen)` and a `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)`.

Anyone have any ideas? Why isn't `iperf` noticing this connection?

**I actually route the packets to a TUN device on machine A, then read them from a userspace program on A, send them to B with a UDP socket, read them on a userspace program on B, then send them via a raw socket with `IP_HDRINCL` disabled. I print out the headers when received on machine A and B, and I don't see anything weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Turned out the problem was fixed by assigning the TUN device on machine A to `eth0`'s IP address. Before, I assigned the TUN device to it's own IP address (I did attempt to remove an IP address from the TUN device, but then it defaulted to `eth1`. That didn't work either.).

I guess some modifications were occurring because of this, or that some sort of tunneling/connection wasn't established by `iperf` because the packets weren't being sent out of `eth0` before.

If anyone has any further insights into how/why this works, I'd be very interested.